# how to send email with graphic via php

Tags: php, email, attachment

I would like to send HTML email with graphic elements included. I have no idea to attach garaphics to this email.

Answer (score 6):

You probably don't want to do an inline attachment by hand, it's far easier, and less error prone to use a library, like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/).
It can attach the inline images, or if you give it some HTML code, it will attach the images by itself and modify the code to display them.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Swift Mailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to bore you with a mediocre explanation here so instead let me link to this great tutorial over at Sitepoint which explained it to me in plain English! - [advanced-email-php](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/advanced-email-php/)

Answer (score 2):

The short version is that you are probably best off creating a HTML formatted messages, and using the header parameter of the php mail function.

```
 $headers = "From: sender@example.com\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
    "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
 mail(to@example.com, 'subject line', 'your message text <strong>with HTML in it</strong>', $headers);
```

The sitepoint.com article referenced by Jimmy provides an excellent and complete description of your options.